# window.external.notify stops working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

**Update 1:**

**I also checked MSDN for the window.external.notify() method, on the MSDN, the method starts with “N" in capital(window.external.Notify()), but at many other places on the Internet, I also saw many examples using "n" in lower case(window.external.notify()). This really confuses me.**

---

It's really odd.
The first time when I used the window.external.notify method, it worked perfectly.

Went to a trip overseas about 2 weeks, got back to home today and couldn't find my latest code which had the notidy method in my Javascript code, but the code for Browser_ScriptNotify method in my C# code is still there.
Searched for 1 hour and found nothing(where did it go?)

Now I coded the Javascript part again and here is the code:

Btw, I am useing jQuery + jQuery Mobile to take care the layout and UI.
The setColor method is called in

> $(document).on("pagecreate", "[data-role='page'].weekday", function
>   () {
>     setColor(this);
>      });

JavaScript:

```
var myNotifier = function (msg) {
    if (window.external) 
        {
            window.external.notify('Hi Mate');
        }

};
function setColor(activePage){
    $(activePage).find('.rightCol').each(function (index, element) {
        var innerRows = $(element).children("div").length;

        if ($(element).hasClass('orange'))
        {
            $(element).children("div").addClass('orange');
        }

        var timeCol = $(element).prev();
        var time = $(timeCol).text().trim();
        var innerRowsDivs = $(element).children("div");

        innerRowsDivs.each(function (index, rowElement) {

            var innerRowContent = $(rowElement).text().trim();

            if (innerRowContent === "") { }
            else
            {
                var room = $(rowElement).find("div").text().trim();
                var trainingClass = $(rowElement).find("strong").text().trim();
                var duration = innerRowContent.substring(innerRowContent.length - 5, innerRowContent.length - 3).trim();
                var message = String('myMsg:open:calender:' + time + '|' + room + '|' + trainingClass + '|' + duration);

                $(rowElement).click(myNotifier(message));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

C# code:

```
   void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Value);
            if (e.Value.Contains("myMsg"))
            {
                if (e.Value.Contains("share"))
                {
                    ShareLinkTask shareMyWebsite = new ShareLinkTask();
                    shareMyWebsite.Title = "WinTech Company";
                    shareMyWebsite.LinkUri = new Uri("http://wintech.azurewebsites.net/", UriKind.Absolute);
                    shareMyWebsite.Message = "Check this awesome website, I'm sure you will find something interesting!";

                    shareMyWebsite.Show();
                }

                if (e.Value.Contains("open"))
                {
                    if (e.Value.Contains("website"))
                    {
                        WebBrowserTask myWebsite = new WebBrowserTask();
                        myWebsite.Uri = new Uri("http://wintech.azurewebsites.net/", UriKind.Absolute);
                        myWebsite.Show();
                    }
                    else
                        if (e.Value.Contains("facebook"))
                        {
                            WebBrowserTask myWebsite = new WebBrowserTask();
                            myWebsite.Uri = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/franva008", UriKind.Absolute);
                            myWebsite.Show();
                        }
                        else
                            // myMsg:open:calender:<Message>
                            if (e.Value.Contains("calender"))
                            {
                                //var message = e.Value.Split(':')[3];
                                //var time = message.Split('|')[0];
                                //var trainingClassAndDuration = message.Split('|')[1];
                                //string[] content = trainingClassAndDuration.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                //string durationString = content[content.Length - 1];
                                //int takeCount = content.Length - 2;
                                //string trainingClass = string.Join(" ", content.Skip(1).Take(takeCount));
                                //string room = content[0];

                                //int duration = Convert.ToInt32(durationString.Substring(0, 2));

                                var message = e.Value.Split(':')[3];
                                var time = message.Split('|')[0];
                                var room = message.Split('|')[1];
                                var trainingClass = message.Split('|')[2];
                                var duration = Convert.ToInt32(message.Split('|')[3]);

                                DateTime startTime = ParseTime(time);
                                DateTime endTime = startTime.AddMinutes(duration);

                                this.CreateAppointment(startTime, endTime, room, trainingClass);
                            }

                }


            }


        }
```

IsScriptEnabled has been set in the xaml
and the Browser_ScriptNotify event has been hooked up in my code as well.

I keep getting an error about jquery:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object 50 has no method 'apply'

and an error about notify

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'notify'

Please  help, these errors have stopped me more than 4 hours, I have read through many similar questions and none of them soloved my problem.

Comment: for jQM, I guess you shouldn't use `pagecreate` to manipulate DOM since page is still in _enhancement_ phase. Use at least `pageinit` or `pageshow`. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Omar Hi Omar, thank you for your reply. I'm using 1.4.0 and I was using pageinit previously and found it is deprecated in jQM 1.4.0, so I changed it to pagecreate.

Comment: `pageshow` is deprecated but still working. Try it just to check if it solves `apply` error. That error has to do with _enhancement_.

Comment: @Omar tried, the error persists. I think it's my code at some where....I finally found my bug for having no method 'notify'. It's because the $(xxx).click(), I changed it to $(xxx).bind("click",function(){........}); now it works. :)

Comment: Good, but _apply_ error persists still?

Comment: @Omar yes, it persists. Oh btw, it's really nice to see you again :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48984/discussion-between-omar-and-franva)

Comment: @Franva A small followup question, Can you post on how you integrated your C# code into a Cordova App? I don't see any articles that allow that. I am trying something similar to get the current WebView reference in my plugin to call navigatetoUri() function on it.